# How to specify the slot of 'v-data-table group-by'

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

[Result photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEabk.png)
I want to express the data horizontally like the result picture.

I want to specify a slot from v-data-table to group by (class), but it is not recognized.

Please let me know if you know how.

```html
    <template #[`item.group-by`]="{ item }">
        
      </template>
```

Please let me know if there is another way other than group by.
Should we swap rowspan or row/col? I'm thinking about it.
[This is the current progress picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQdbP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change your data model like below.

```
data: () => ({
  headers: {
    {text: 'class'},
    {text: 'school1'},
    {text: 'school2'},
    {text: 'school3'}
  },
  items: {
    ... If you need to keep your items, use computedItems. ... 
  }
},
computed: {
  computedItems () {
    ... rebuild your items like this ...
    return {
      {class: 'A', school1: [...], school2: [...], school3: [...]},
      {class: 'B', school1: [...], school2: [...], school3: [...]},
      {class: 'C', school1: [...], school2: [...], school3: [...]},
    }
  }
}
```

then use [v-slot:item.name](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots-item.%3Cname%3E)

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="computedItems">
  <template v-slot:item.school1="{item}">
    <template v-for>
      <img src="...">
    </template>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:item.school2="{item}">
    <template v-for>
      <img src="...">
    </template>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:item.school3="{item}">
    <template v-for>
      <img src="...">
    </template>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```